# Incorrect test suites order in reportng html report

Tags: testng, reportng

My test launch consists of some test suites specified in testng.xml. In html reportng report I see test suites logs in incorrect order in comparison to actually they run and I specified to run them in xmls.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks In Advance!

**Update** (to Antonio):

*I'm sorry that my samples are in Russian*

I see the following in my reportng html test report:
[image]

It's totally incorrect order in comparison to actual tests running order (and testng xml test suite):

```
<suite name="FullSuiteName" verbose="1">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="thisIs5thSuiteOnTheFigure.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="thisIs3rdSuiteOnTheFigure.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="thisIs4thSuiteOnTheFigure.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="thisIs1stSuiteOnTheFigure.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="thisIs2ndSuiteOnTheFigure.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Test reports for each test suite is shown in correct order.

Actually, I launch my test suite via Maven task from Jenkins. Which details do I need post here?

And I cannot understand how to fix it.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? I.e: content or visual example of your xml or logs files. How are you executing the tests?

Comment: @Antonio I updated description with some details

Comment: Sorry man. But I don't figure what is going on here....

Answer (score 1):

The report shows the order in which the tests were run. In this case, your suites were run in the order that it shows in the report. TestNG does not run tests in a top-down order (see [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/rqWQ7SthPCE)). It seems to choose and see which one is the fastest, and runs those first. If you need tests to run in order, you can set this via [dependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) or [priorities](http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-test-case-priority).